# Why is Azure Data Studio Profiler not capturing stored procedures with large input data?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, sql-server-profiler, azure-data-studio

I am analysing the performance of stored procedures in an Azure SQL database, but when using the profiler in Azure Data Studio, I cannot see some of the stored procedures, specifically those that have a large dataset input.

After investigation in a test environment, if I spread the input dataset across multiple stored procedure executions, I am able to see the execution in the profiler like this:

[image]

Why is the Profiler hiding the stored procedure executions with large input datasets?

Is it possible to increase the character limit in the TextData for example?

Comment: I assume you are passing a TVP? How many rows?

Comment: Around 3000 rows using a User-Defined Table type with 19 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large TVPs are not captured by extended events to avoid impact on overall database performance. ADS Profiler uses an extended event ring buffer. [KB4468102](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4468102-fix-excessive-memory-usage-when-you-trace-rpc-events-that-involve-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-c68aa214-26f1-98de-6b4d-c7dcad82dbd4), which applies to Azure SQL Database as well, mentions a limit for TVPs but the threshold is not documented AFAIK.

I found through experimentation the limit depends on not just the number for rows passed in the TVP but the schema of the table type as well.